# How to get the class that was passed to a Thread class?

Tags: java, multithreading, pthreads

I have the code in java below, the TaskControl class implements the runable class and I need to access the contents of this TaskControl class according to thread, something like:

'threads.get(0).getTaskControl().getAttribute();'

```
public void multipleQueriesStart(){
    queryIndex = new QueryGroupHash[nThreads];
    buildQueryIndexGroup(nThreads);
    for(File xmlFile: xmlFileList){
        System.out.println(xmlFile.getName());
        threads.clear();
        try {                
            if(nThreads > Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
                nThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
            if(nQueriesPerGroup > 0)
                for(int i = 0; i < nThreads ; i++){
                    threads.add(new Thread(new TaskControl(xmlFile, 
                            queryIndex[i], semantic, nGroups)));
                }
            else
                threads.add(new Thread(new TaskControl(xmlFile, 
                            queryIndex[0], semantic, nGroups)));
            for(Thread t: threads){
                t.start();
                //t.sleep(t.getId()*100); //ordena o resultado printado
            }
            for(Thread t: threads){
                t.join();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in Thread");
            Logger.getLogger(QueryProcessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When? Inside the Thread? Outside the thread but before completion? After completion? etc.

Comment: *`t.get(0)`*? Is `t` a `Thread`? If so, it doesn't have a `get(int)` method. Did you mean `threads.get(0)`?

Comment: To have access to the `TaskControl` object, create a `List<TaskControl> taskControls` and keep the `threads` and `taskControls` lists in sync. Or if you don't want sync'd lists, create a class with 2 fields, and have a list of those.

Comment: thanks @Andreas, i corrected the post. Creating a list of TaskControl is a solution but i just want to now if is another way to access the object used to create a Thread.

Comment: The answer is no, because `Thread` does not expose the `Runnable` given in the constructor.